# What does this definition of diagonalizable matrices mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

In Serge Lang’s Linear Algebra, I don’t understand what this means on page 93:

> > If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix in $K$, we say that $A$ can be diagonalized (in $K$) if the linear map on $K^n$ represented by $A$ can be diagonalized.

Okay, so is this just referring to the map $L:K^n\to K^n$ such that $L($X$) = AX$? If so, for this matrix to be diagonalizable, must $A$ be a diagonal matrix, thus it would have been a lot simpler to just say that $A$ needs to be diagonal in the first place? I just don’t get the way it’s defined at all.

Comment: No, this depends on the basis:  $A$ could be diagonal or not in different bases.  This the difference between "diagonal" and "diagonalizable."

Comment: I don't have Lang handy but it is probably more general than that and likely equivalent to the existence of a matrix $P$ with entries in $K$ for which $P^{-1} A P$ is diagonal. This kind of definition is not that informative but there are useful algorithms and methods for seeing if such $P$ exist and computing one in the event that it does exist. In some books it is possible that a matrix will be said to be capable of being "diagonalized," without reference to a field, if there exists such a matrix $P$  with entries in some extension of the field $K$.

Comment: @Randall I can see that making sense, I think I’m confused about what “linear map on $K^n$ represented by $A$” means.

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath you got that part right:  that just means the map $X \mapsto AX$.

Comment: @Randall So $A$ doesn’t even need to be diagonal to be diagonalizable since at the end of the day, $M_B^B(F)$ is only interested in the basis $B$ chosen to represent vectors in $K^n$. Is this correct/what you meant originally?

Comment: Yep.  $L$ can appear to be non-diagonal in one basis, but diagonal in another.  Choice of basis is really important.

Comment: Lang basically says that a matrix is diagonalisable if the linear map it represents is diagonalisable. He should have defined diagonalisable linear maps in earlier passages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example is sometimes better than a whole theory. Take
$$A =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

The map $L$ associated to $A$ is the map $L : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$L(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y  \end{pmatrix}, \quad \text{i.e.} \quad L(x,y) =(x+y,2y)$$

Of course $A$ is not a diagonal matrix. However, if you consider $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(1,1)$, then $(e_1,e_2)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and you get $L(e_1)=e_1$ and $L(e_2)=2e_2$, so the matrix of $L$ is the basis $(e_1,e_2)$ is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} $$

This matrix is diagonal, which means that $L$ (or equivalently $A$) is diagonalizable (even if $A$ is not diagonal).

Comment: It helped a lot to see it play out in an example. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath You are welcome !